# How to insert header info in Linkedin Oauth

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

Using the Linkedin OAuth system users can log into my website. Everything works fine, but when users get to the linkedin screen they get to see a screen in which I think some information is missing. In the screenshot below you see my logo on the right, but left of that is a space which seems like it is missing some information. I searched around the Linkedin app settings but can't find anything there.

Does anybody know what information should actually be there and where I can supply this information? Should it be in the Linkedin App settings on [developer.linkedin.com](http://developer.linkedin.com/), or do I need to supply it with the OAuth call somehow?

All tips are welcome!

ps. The reason I'm asking this on SO is because Linkedin actually [directs people with questions about OAuth to Stackoverflow](https://developer.linkedin.com/support).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can fill this information yourself. If you are already logged in into LinkedIn, it will display your picture in the place of the placeholder photo, and your full name next to it, in the blank space you see between the logo and the image.

You can do nothing about this, it's just the way LinkedIn sets up its oauth authorization page. I hope this helps.

Comment: It's not really the answer I was hoping for, but I guess you're right.. :-( . Thanks for letting me know!